# Present ViewController same as control centre works in iPhone

Tags: ios, user-interface, swift5, bottom-sheet, presentviewcontroller

I would like to present bottom sheet the way it is shown in the attached screenshot on a button click.

- With transparent background
- Swappable close bottom sheet
- With that top rectangular bar icon which usually I have noticed in the when we swipe down/up the control centre menu

I am familiar with normal present screen, even with transparent background. But, I am really not sure exactly how can I achieve this UI.
Hence, I am not attaching any code, because I am still searching for it.
Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Consider using FloatingPanel

Check out this GitHub project:
https://github.com/scenee/FloatingPanel

```
let  = FloatingPanelController()
let contentVC = YOUR_VIEW_CONTROLLER()
floatingPanel.set(contentViewController: contentVC)
self.present(floatingPanel, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Let it be removable by a swipe-down

```
floatingPanel.isRemovalInteractionEnabled = true
```

For customizing floating panel you need to implement your layout with the 'Floating Panel Layout' protocol

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, FloatingPanelControllerDelegate {
    ... {
        floatingPanel = FloatingPanelController(delegate: self)
        floatingPanel.layout = MyFloatingPanelLayout()
    }
}

class MyFloatingPanelLayout: FloatingPanelLayout {
    let position: FloatingPanelPosition = .bottom
    let initialState: FloatingPanelState = .tip
    var anchors: [FloatingPanelState: FloatingPanelLayoutAnchoring] {
        return [
            .full: FloatingPanelLayoutAnchor(absoluteInset: 16.0, edge: .top, referenceGuide: .safeArea),
            .half: FloatingPanelLayoutAnchor(fractionalInset: 0.5, edge: .bottom, referenceGuide: .safeArea),
            .tip: FloatingPanelLayoutAnchor(absoluteInset: 44.0, edge: .bottom, referenceGuide: .safeArea),
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: You are welcome. It's always nice to improve :)